# How can I split a string into an array in one operation, but only when the line contains a given pattern?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, string-matching

I have to match a line in a file and capture the lines contents.
The line is as as follows:

```
key:value key:value abc:123
```

I have a block of code processing different lines in the file based on the line content.
The above line can be identified by the key "abc" being present in the line.
I need one regex which does the following

1. Check if "abc" is present in the line
2. if "abc" is present get the contents in the form of an array

I am able to do these separately

```
#gives me an array of the key,value pairs
array = line.scan(/\w+:\d+/) 
#matches "abc:value" but does not give me the other keys
/.*(abc:\d+)/.match(line)
```

Looking for a way do this in one operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't Complicate Things

A regular expression, especially a single monolithic one, isn't the solution for everything. Even when it's *possible*, overly complex expressions don't make your code more readable or more maintainable. Unless your employer is charging *you* for each line of code, don't be afraid to use multiple lines of code to express a concept.

### Use a Conditional Expression

You can use a conditional expression in your statement to match within a single line. For example:

```
line = 'key:value key:value abc:123'
line.scan /(\S+:\S+)/ if line =~ /abc:/
# => [["key:value"], ["key:value"], ["abc:123"]]
```

This will only split the line into an array of matches if it first matches the condition in the *if* statement. However, note that you're still fundamentally doing two regular expression matches.

If you're trying to avoid performing two regular expression matches, perhaps for performance reasons inside a tight loop, you can do something similar with a string pattern match as your condition. For example:

```
line = 'key:value key:value abc:123'
line.scan /(\S+:\S+)/ if line.include? 'abc:'
# => [["key:value"], ["key:value"], ["abc:123"]]
```

The results are the same, but [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) uses a regular expression match while the conditional uses [String#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F). The latter *may* be faster.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
array = line.scan(/\w+:\d+/) if line[/abc:\d+/]
```